# RecursionError at /

Tags: django

maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

[image: screen]

Ребята,когда запускаю Django-project localhost,выдает это. С чем это может быть связано ?

Comment: [максимальная глубина рекурсии превышена при вызове объекта Python](https://translate.yandex.ru/?lang=en-ru&text=maximum%20recursion%20depth%20exceeded%20while%20calling%20a%20Python%20object) - какое именно слово непонятно?

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите шаблон `base.html` в вопрос. Вы можете это сделать, нажав кнопку [edit].